# Can an HTML button be used to upload a file for use with the W3C File API?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a thumbnail interface mockup, and I would like to add the ability to upload an image. According to my mockup, the interface looks like this:

[image: Thumbnail interface]

The intent was that the user would click on the "Add Icon" button, and a file dialog would pop up, just like the one that pops up when a file input is clicked. I would like the use the W3C's File API to handle the file upload asynchronously, and display the thumbnail in the gray area above the button once the upload is complete.

So, I'd like to upload a file without using a file input HTML element. I tried working with a hidden file input element and calling its `click` event handler with Javascript when the "Add Icon" button is clicked, but the call didn't do anything. I think security might have some reason to do with this.

Has anyone had any luck using an HTML `button` to upload a file before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick I always do is wrapping the hidden `file input` into a `label` tag and then putting my custom `input` elements in the `label` tag. By defenition clicking on anything inside the `label` tag should trigger the `input` inside. No JavaScript needed at all!

```
<label>
    <div>
        My custom file input
    </div>
<input type="file" id="file"/>
</label>
```

CSS: `input{visibility:hidden;}` Please note that you can't use `display:none` because then the element will not render. Still you can make the element `width:0; height:0;` to hide `input` element completely.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hjhF/)

Using HTML file API is a little different. Read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) at Mozilla Developer Network to leran more.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! One caveat is that a `button` can't be placed inside the `label` tag, so I had to stylize a `div`. So much for semantics, but it works.